# Where did Bronn shoot the arrow from?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

In the episode "Blackwater" (S02EP09) of *Game of Thrones*, Bronn releases a single arrow and ignites the wildfire in the Blackwater Bay.

**Where was Bronn standing when he released the arrow?**

Was he on the shore near Mud Gate and did he shoot the arrow into Blackwater Bay or into Blackwater Rush?

For that matter, where did the Lannister ship come from? Did it approach Stannis via the Blackwater Rush or did it set sail from Blackwater Bay and never enter the rush?

Maybe this is described in the book?

Comment: In the books, Bronn was holding the towers raising the chain and had nothing to do with the fire. The fire was started by a burning ship ramming the boat with the wildfire inside it. The fire came from normal anti-ship weapons, such as fire arrows and burning pitch.

Comment: Oh, that's a big difference! Thanks!

Comment: I think the details of that particular scene are ones we have to accept as "It doesn't make very much sense, but looks awesome so it's worth it". (if I remember correctly, GRRM personally wrote that episode, so we can't just blame the producers this time!)

Comment: @user568458: Why does it not make sense? Bronn has a massive target to hit (an oil stain on relatively calm water surface), could fire several arrows even if he would miss, and the lack of a fiery boat makes the approach less suspicious to Stannis' troops, who now only realize that it's a trap when they're right next to the boat. If anything, Bronn's arrow can be avoided less than the single burning boat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Somewhere downstream of the [Mud Gate](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Mud_Gate)

Sorry, can't seem to give you anymore information than that.

As you can see in [this video](https://youtu.be/bxKzT7AzK1c?t=1m22s), Bronn is standing on what seems to be a rock bank down stream of the Mud Gate, close enough that he can see Tyrion's fire signal, and far enough out that he could hit the wildfire soaked water near the bulk of the Baratheon fleet.

Tyrion and Joffrey's party are seen standing atop the battlements, near a gate, that gate was predicted by Tyrion to be the focal point of the Baratheon fleet's attacking point during the [Battle of the Blackwater](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Battle_of_the_Blackwater). A clever <strike>half-</strike>man who predicted this correctly.

Whether the wildfire laden ship approaces from the [Blackwater Rush](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Blackwater_Rush) or merely in the [Bay](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Blackwater_Bay) is irrelevant, as not enough detail is shown about this area or scene. Most likely though, it would have approached from the Rush, or even simply from the gate.

---

### An addendum about the books

As pointed out in the comments [by TLP](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/121711/where-did-bronn-shoot-the-arrow-from#comment299626_121711), Bronn has nothing to do with the lighting of the wildfire, [it is in fact a burning ship that plows into the wildfire laden one which triggers the explosion](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Battle_of_the_Blackwater#The_Battle).

Stannis' fleet is allowed to come into the Bay, lured in fact by the entirety of Joffrey's fleet. They are cut off from escape by a gigantic chain, so they are well into the Bay.